# Connecting different voltage sensor

Tags: esp8266

I have a very basic question. I have a esp8266 device that needs to read from an analog device. the device runs at 24V, and the ESP at 3.3V. Should I connect both grounds? This is the schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current from the sensor must run back to ground, in addition the 3.3v from the sensor will be 3.3v above the ground of the sensor. Because of this is important to make sure the voltage of both grounds is the same, do this by making sure the cables are large enough to support the current flowing though them (the resistance in the cable will create voltage when current flows though the wire, V= I*R to minimize the voltage make sure the cables resistance is low)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must. Unless the grounds are already connected via some other route.